# How to initialize an object array that was created inside a Structure in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

No matter what I do, I end up with Object reference not set to an instance of an object at runtime.  The problem is RptParamList().

The Structure is...

```
Partial Class WebReports_RptGeneric
    Inherits Page
    Protected ObjUtils As New Utilities
    Protected ObjDtn As New DataTable

    Structure SchedParms
        Shared ReportName As String
        Shared RptParamList() As ParameterValue
    End Structure

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim objSecurit As New STISecurity
        Dim intRc As Integer
        Dim objAudit As New Audits
        ...

    Public Sub XqtSaveSched(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'Get Report Name and Report Parameters
        paramList.Clear()
        dt.Reset()
        dt = ObjUtils.GetDataTableForQuery("sp_GetPosFieldNames", paramList)
        ReDim SchedParms.RptParamList(13)
        SchedParms.RptParamList(0).Name = "rpFY" (BLOWS UP HERE!!)
        SchedParms.RptParamList(0).Value = CStr(Session("FY"))
        SchedParms.RptParamList(1).Name = "rpUserID"
        SchedParms.RptParamList(1).Value = "1000000"
        SchedParms.RptParamList(2).Name = "rpShowLinks"
        SchedParms.RptParamList(2).Value = CStr(False)
```

I tried adding the ReDim statement as an initializer, but that didn't work.  I also tried SchedParms.RptParamList(0) = new ParameterValue() , but that didn't work either.

Comment: `Redim` will create the array, not the `ParameterValue` objects for it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array with the `New` keyword, otherwise `RptParamList` will be `Nothing`

```
Shared RptParamList As ParameterValue() = New ParameterValue(13) {}
```

If the array can grow, use a `List(Of ParameterValue)`, rather than redimmming an array. Lists do that automatically.

```
Shared RptParamList As New List(Of ParameterValue)()
```

Then add items with the `Add` method

```
SchedParms.RptParamList.Add(New ParameterValue())
```